# Ruby: Locate class definition at run time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an odd probably with rails right now... a class is being defined somewhere, and I can't find it. Grepping for "class ClassName" hasn't managed to locate it, but it's definitely there when I load up the rails console. It's just a vanilla class inheriting from Object with nothing else defined... quite boring. So, what I'd like is a way to figure out where this class constant was originally defined from the rails console. Something to print out the value of '__ FILE __' when this class was declared, in other words. I feel like some type of metaprogramming should make this possible.

I thought of just doing

```
ClassName.class_exec { __FILE__ }
```

But this just always gives me the current file.

Comment: Why don't you just give us the name of the class and someone will probably find it for you

Comment: Funny story... the class was called MatchData. It's defined in core ruby, of course, for regex results. I sure feel stupid! The answer here is useful in the general case, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hook method `inherited`, if defined, gets called whenever a subclass is created.  Therefore:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Object
  def self.inherited(child)
    target_class = "Child"
    raise "#{target_class} defined" if child.name == target_class
  end
end

class Parent
end

class Child < Parent    # => /tmp/foo.rb:6:in `inherited': Child defined (RuntimeError)
                        # =>         from /tmp/foo.rb:13

end
```